# Is there anything like "std::and" or "std::or"?

Tags: c++, algorithm, boolean, std, short-circuiting

Given a container of boolean values (An example is `std::vector<bool>`), is there a standard function that returns `true` if all the values are `true` ("and") or `true` if at least one value is `true` ("or"), with short circuit evalutation ?

I digged trough [www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count_if/) this morning but couldn't find anything close.

Comment: You can easily implement your own...

Comment: @Dani: Indeed. But even if the code is trivial, if there is anything that already exists, why would I rewrite it ?

Comment: @ereOn, things that are easily implemented don't go into c++. if you want that try c# or even some interpreter.

Comment: @Dani Nonsense. See `<algorithm>` and `<functional>` for tons of convenience functions and classes whose implementation is trivial.

Comment: @Dani: There is no pride to get from writing something trivial. No offense, but your comment reminds me of a guy at my work that refuses to use shared pointers and `std::string` because he **knows** how to do that himself. Sure he does, but as a result his code is often unmaintainable and cluttered with trivial tricks.

Comment: Did you look at the size of std::string? its huge, not trivial. however, 3 line `for`, is.

Comment: cplusplus.com is a poor resource.

Comment: @Dani: `std::string` is "huge"?

Comment: string after concating its different files is 15312 lines

Comment: @Dani: Repeat those 3 lines one hundred times and compare it to what you would have got using one of the "one-liners" below: you just lost 200 hundred lines of trivial code that brings **nothing**.

Comment: @ereOn, you can say it for pretty much everything... and if you excessively use this in your application just make an inlined function/macro for it

Comment: @Dani: So I would end up with a one-line, inlinable function maintained by me in place of a... one-line, inlinable function maintained by the people who built my compiler. What is the next step ? Rewriting my own `memcpy` or `std::copy` ? After all, it is just a single `for` loop.

Comment: I don't know about `std::copy`, but `memcpy` uses some processor specific instructions which make it faster... and what I meant is that the c++ library will just become more bloated when people like you ask for features that you can use for yourself. a simple static hello world is already few kilobytes when all it does is write 1 line to the screen.

Comment: @Dani: The good thing is that there must be a lot of people "like me" since C++0x includes `std::all_of` and `std::any_of` :) Moreover, if these simple functions are inlinable (which they surely are), what size difference with "rolling out my own version of these functions" does it make anyway ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can implement by:

**AND:**

```
std::find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), false) == vector.end() // all the values are true
```

**OR:**

```
std::find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), true) != vector.end() //at least one value is true
```

Comment: Well sometimes I guess I'm searching too hard... And I can even use `find_if` with a function object if I need to perform a more complicated check on the values. Thank you very much !

Comment: I accepted FredOverflow's answer because his solution is more straightforward. Upvoted this one for fairness and because it is really clever.

Comment: @ereOn: But you said that you can't use Fred's answer as your solution.

Comment: @Tomalak: Indeed. I can't use it right now, but it still seems to be the recommended way to do this. I actually implemented the two solutions and commented out one of them until I can use it.

Comment: @ereOn: Recommended if you have C++0x. I won't use non-standard features in critical production code, though. If you want a standard C++ solution -- and, incidentally, one that actually works for you ereOn -- then this is the correct answer, at present, to the stated problem. That a future standard makes it a bit easier is an interesting sidenote.

Answer (score 53):

> is there a standard function that returns true if all the values are true ("and")

```
std::all_of(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](bool x) { return x; } )
```

> or true if at least one value is true ("or")

```
std::any_of(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](bool x) { return x; } )
```

> with short circuit evalutation?

I just inserted print statements into the lambda, and yes, both functions perform short-circuiting.

Comment: +1. I knew this would be added some day. I unfortunately cannot use C++0x right now on my project, but that's good to know. Thank you.

Comment: @ereOn: neither can I (at work), so I went ahead and created them (not in the namespace std, of course) to help with future migration :)

Comment: as @Morwenn said there is missing Unary Predicate

Comment: @HannaKhalil Thanks for the feedback, I just updated my answer!

Answer (score 13):

You can use the function objects [`logical_and`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/logical_and) and [`logical_or`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/logical_or) in conjunction with a reduction to accomplish that.

[`accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) calculates the reduction. Hence:

```
bool any = std::accumulate(foo.begin(), foo.end(), false, std::logical_or<>());
bool all = std::accumulate(foo.begin(), foo.end(), true, std::logical_and<>());
```

Caveat: this is **not** using short-circuiting (the `accumulate` function knows nothing about short-circuiting even though the functors do), while Igor’s clever solution is.

Comment: How about `std::accumulate` for reduction?

Comment: Is this using short-circuit evalutation rules?

Comment: FYI this does not compile

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need a generic algorithm for different container types...

As you are looking for short circuit evaluation, you may give std::valarray a chance. For `and` use `valarray::min() == true` for `or` you could use `std::find` as mentioned by Igor.

In case you know the number of elements to store at compile time, you could even use a std::bitset:

```
bitset<100> container();

//... fill bitset

bool or = container.any();
bool and = container.count() == container.size();
```